# Signing a large file using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I need to sign a large binary file containing a firmware and then validate this signature at the target device receiving it. After reading some articles I concluded a way to do this, but I am not sure whether it's supposed to be done this way. Below is what I've done so far:

Sender generates a private key:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_pubexp:3 -out privkey-ID.pem
```

Sender generates the public key using the private key:

```
$ openssl pkey -in privkey-ID.pem -out pubkey-ID.pem -pubout
```

Sender generates the digest and sign the file using it:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privkey-ID.pem -out out.sha256 rootfs.jffs2
```

Receiver verifies the signature:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey-ID.pem -signature out.sha256 rootfs.jffs2
```

On executing the 4th step I am getting a "Verification OK" response but I am not sure if it's done correctly.

Also the requirement is to use a symmetric key for signing. As far as I understand signing with a symmetric key means one must use the same key at both the sender and the receiver, but here I am signing with a private key and verifying with a public key.

Clarifications on the above points is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. Perhaps Information Security Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You generated a SHA256 digest (or hash; a short value which represents the whole file), signed it and verified the signature using asymmetric RSA algorithm.

Asymmetric RSA algorithm uses a public and private key. Anyone can encrypt data with the public key and only the owner of private key can decrypt it. Signing works in opposite, the owner can encrypt data with private key to sign it, and everyone can decrypt it to verify the signature.

But according to your requirement you need to use symmetric algorithm, such as HMAC-SHA256. Internally it computes the same SHA-256 digest and then it signs it with provided key.

```
cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "sharedkey"
```

It has no separate commands to sign and verify, you only need to run the same operation on both devices and compare results.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.. Could you please explain a bit more on the signing part. Does that mean that if we sign a file with a private key then it can be verified by everyone who has a public key derived from this private key and the vice-versa is not possible... ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is is how asymmetric works. There is one-way math relation between numbers stored in private and public key. It is computationally very hard (= not possible in reasonable time) to reverse it.

Comment: You chose RSA, it has a specific property, both private and public key can be used for both encryption and decryption, but only in pair with the second key. So if you reverse encryption, you use private key to "encrypt" (= sign), anyone with public key can "decrypt" (= verify). It is not possible with other asymmetric algorithms. There are other algorithms intended for signing only (eg. DSA, ECDSA).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Actually I have two requirement here. First I need to encrypt a file and then sign it. Since the file size can be anywhere between 5 MB to 25 MB, I am planning to use openSSL S/MIME for this. This file which I have mentioned here is actually a firmware image which needs to be downloaded to a linux device. So I need to have the private key somewhere in the linux device to decrypt the firmware image. After decryption if I need to verify the signature then I need to have the public key as well in the device.

Comment: Maintaining both the keys at the same place will be against asymmetric encryption logic I guess. So if I am using a sharedkey as you suggested using HMAC, then that also needs to be shared along with the encrypted image for verifying the signature. Along with this I may also need to send the sha256 file (digest) to signature verification. This would be very difficult to do implementation wise. I prefer to have a single file. (Possibly the encrypted firmware image with the shared key and the sha or the digest value.) Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ah, you said nothing about encrypting in the question :)

Comment: yes.. Sorry for that.. :) Do you have any suggestions to the problem which I had posted above.?